# Iphone TableViewController Logic Error!

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need quick help! ):

I'm really confused on how to use TableViewContoller with webservice to retrieve the datasource.
Here's how i do it.

I have a Model class where i define all the variable. Example ( Username, datetime)
Also, in the model class i have a method where it will use ASIHTTPRequest to retrieve the json datasource and create an NSMutableArray of Model class to create and store the object.

Then, in my Tableviewcontroller. I trigger the method in the model class that retrieve the json in the Viewdidload method and access the NSMutableArray to try to set my table cell.

However, nothing appear even when i retrieved the json successfully. (I'm guessing the table rendered itself before the json is retrieved back).

Is there some programming design issue with what i'm doing? ):
Give me an idea! THANKS!!!

---

EDIT!! (Found what happened)
Sorry guys! It's my bad.
In the return number of section method, i return 0 instead of 1.
Which is the reason why it does not show. spent 2hrs on this. T.T

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the `NSMutableArray` has been filled (aka the request has been completed) use `[self.tableView reloadData];`

I'm assuming you also have set your `cell.textLabel.text` property with the array's data appropriately.

Comment: Yes i do. (:
Thanks! But i still have the issue of not knowing where to place the reloadData as the method where the request is completed lies at my Model class where i cant access the tableView. ):

Comment: Oops my mistake.  You have to move the code where the asynchronous call takes place to the view controller.  Within the `requestFinished` method, run the `reloadData` method.

Comment: So my "getAllFeeds" cannot be in other class except the view controller? I will give it a try! Thanks. (:

Comment: As Jamie suggested, you could use `NSNotifications` to use it in multiple view controllers, but each view controller will be required to be set as an observer of the notification to act on the data and instead of returning data from the method, the data would have to be stored in a property of the object.

Comment: I'm done transferring the method over to the controller, but somehow my table did not render any row despite me using reloadData. I'm sure there's data in my NSMutableArray. :/
Another issue now, but thanks!! (:

Comment: The array that contains the requested data should be a member of the view controller. Ensure that is set.

Comment: Yea! it's set.
NSMutableArray *feeds;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *feeds;

And in the requestdidfinish, i did add the required stuff in using self.feeds = ""//populate data;
and log it which show there's 3data inside.

Yet, in another method(viewdidload), the log show there's no data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below method.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   [tableview reloadData]; 
}
```

once you get data from your web service and you have array for that reload tableview data. 
I am not much sure about your response data so I just give you assumption.

Hope this help.

Comment: How do i do that in dynamic? As model are not allowed to access the view. So i cannot place this in the model where my method(determine if data is retrieved) lies at right? 

However in my view, there's no method or ways to tell if my data is retrieved. So i'm quite confused about that. ):
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Done that. Populated my response inside an NSMutableArray.
However, in my viewdidload, i trigger the method to populate the data.
but the table seem to render first before getting the response back which result in zero row shown. ):

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider posting an NSNotification from your model class once the data is retrieved successfully.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"JSONDataDownloadSuccessful" object:nil];
```

then in your UITableViewController you can add an observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter] defaultCenter]  addObserver:self selector:@selector(JSONDataUpdated) name:@"JSONDataDownloadSuccessful" object:nil];
```

For more information, look at the NSNotificationCenter class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps.

Jamie

Comment: If he uses `NSNotifications`, he will not be able to return a value from his function, but would instead have to store the value as a property of the model. In which case, he could use the observer to reload the table data.